# Paypal Sandbox link DEAD? How to test buttons? Catch-22 situation

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

So here's the situation:

1) As per Paypal's sandbox docs, we should go to this url to create test buttons: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/

2) The link is dead.

3) Indian Paypal support says contact paypal USA.

4) US Paypal doesn't reply for over 15 days.

Anyone here facing the same problem and have any workaround for this?

What I want to do is test some buttons before deploying on live site. I "could" test real buttons with $1 or $0.5, but Indian Paypal doesn't allow other Indian Papyal to pay! :S

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You still have issues with this? What's the error that https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/ is throwing for you?
It's working fine for me here.

Either way, the direct link to create PayPal buttons, in Sandbox, through the 'button manager' is https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/?cmd=_web-tools&fli=true&fli=true